# distribution of sum of indicators

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence

Assume we have two sequences of random elements $X_{n}$ and $Y_{n}$ on some normed space $(S, \|\cdot\|_S)$ and defined on the same probability space such that 
$$
X_{n} \stackrel{d}{\to} \phi(Z)
$$
and
$$
Y_{n} \stackrel{d}{\to} \psi(Z)
$$
for some r.v. $Z$ and some continuous operators $\phi$ and $\psi$. Next, let us construct the following sequence of r.v.:
$$
T_{n} = X_{n} I\{X_{n} \in C\} + Y_{n} I\{X_{n} \in \bar{C}\}.
$$

Does this mean then that
$$
T_{n} \stackrel{d}{\to} \phi(Z) I\{\phi(Z) \in C \} + \psi(Z) I\{\phi(Z) \in \bar{C} \}
$$
and
$$
\|T_{n}\|_S \stackrel{d}{\to} \|\phi(Z)\|_S I\{\phi(Z) \in C \} + \|\psi(Z)\|_S I\{\phi(Z) \in \bar{C} \}?
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\def\dto{\xrightarrow{\mathrm{d}}}$This is not true in general.

Counter-example: Take $(S, \|·\|_S) = (\mathbb{R}, |·|)$, a random variable $Z \in U(0, 1)$, and$$X
_n = Z \sim U(0, 1),\ Y_n = 1 - Z \sim U(0, 1), \quad \forall n \in \mathbb{N}_+
$$
then $|X_n| = X_n$, $|Y_n| = Y_n$, and$$
X_n \dto Z, \quad Y_n \dto Z.
$$

Now take $C = \left( 0, \dfrac{1}{2} \right)$, then$$
T_n = Z I_C(Z) + (1 - Z) I_{C^c}(Z) \sim U\left( 0, \frac{1}{2} \right),
$$
and $|T_n| = T_n$, but$$
Z I_C(Z) + Z I_{C^c}(Z) = Z \sim U(0, 1) \Longrightarrow T_n \not\dto Z I_C(Z) + Z I_{C^c}(Z).
$$

Comment: great! Would it be possible that the statement is true under some additional conditions?

Comment: @Mr.M If $ϕ$ (or $ψ$) is constant and $I_C$ (or $I_{C^c}$) is continuous at this constant, then the conclusion holds.

Comment: only in this case? isn't it possible to impose some conditions on $\phi$ and $\psi$? What if $Z$ is the elements from some Hilbert space and $\phi$ and $\psi$ are projections of $Z$ on the cone $C$? I can not figure it out myself...

Comment: @Mr.M The condition I mentioned uses Slutsky's theorem and the continuous mapping theorem to derive the result. In general, however, $X_n$ and $Y_n$ may have certain relations as in this counter-example, so conditions only on $ϕ$, $ψ$ and $Z$ are not sufficient to ensure the desired convergence if no other information about $\{X_n\}$ and $\{Y_n\}$ is known.